# Plotting data structured (x,y,value)

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a dataset using `imagesc` in Matlab. 
The dataset is structured like this:

```
x1  y1  value1
x2  y2  value2
x3  y3  value3
...
```

**The problem:**
when I try to plot it like this:

```
imagesc(x,y,value)
```

the figure is only in one dimension.

It works well when I plot it with `plot3`, using the values for the z-axis.

How can I visualize this dataset using `imagesc`?

Comment: I have described what I have tried. The problem for me is the shape of the data, every row is one coordinate with a value. I know that this works fine for plot3, but I want it in an imagesc. I have tried reshaping the data, but without any luck.

Comment: you can use plot3 and set the view orientation to be looking from the top. Then you will get plot looks like the one you want from imagesc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imagesc` needs a matrix structure rather than the 3 vector you mentioned, and assumes that the data is used in uniform space grids. So I'd use `scatter` instead to begin with.  A way to still use `imagesc` is to interpolate to an uniform grid and construct a matrix out of the 3 vectors you have:

Comment: Thanky you, Scatter was exactly what I was looking for. I will try your suggestion for imagesc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your non-uniform data the function you are looking for is `griddata`.
It handles the interpolation and returns a matrix of values.
This can be plotted by `imagesc`, `surf` or whatever.

`scatter` is usually the better way, but that depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking the source code of imagesc function. You can see how it is made. To see it, write:

```
edit imagesc
```